# Push list of objects to another object in angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

I have two separate objects which is shown below

```
Object1 =  [{value:'A/B'},{value:'A/B/C'},{value:'A/F'},{value:'A/'}];

Object2 =[{option:'A/'},{option:'A/B'}];
```

Now i need to modify the **Object2** by adding a new attribute so that the Object2 must look like this

```
 Object2 = [{option:'A/',
            directories:[{value:'A/'},{value:'A/B'},{value:'A/B/C'},{value:'A/F'}]},
           {option:'A/B',
            directories:[{value:'A/B'},{value:'A/B/C'},{value:'A/F'},{value:'A/'}]}];
```

The changes what i need is

- In directories attribute the first value should be the option value
- Other values should be the remaining values that should come from Object1

I have tried the following code

```
angular.forEach(Object2,function(value,key){

 angular.forEach(Object1,function(value,key){

        //I need the code here

  });
});
```

Comment: _I have two separate objects_ just so you know. it's an array of objects :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
  angular.forEach($scope.Object2,function(value,key){
      value.directories = angular.copy($scope.Object1);
      for (var i=0; i < value.directories.length; i++) {
        if (value.directories[i].value === value.option) {
            var item = value.directories.splice(i,1);  
            value.directories.unshift(item[0]);
            break;
        }
      }
  });
```

basically after adding the directories array to your object you can find the index of the object that you want in the start of array remove it and add it back to the beginning of the array.

**[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/k45duoOKmwIAJRhPrKqJ?p=preview)**

Comment: Your out put will be like this  `[{"option":"A/","directories":[{"value":"A/B"},{"value":"A/B/C"},{"value":"A/F"},{"value":"A/"}]},{"option":"A/B","directories":[{"value":"A/B"},{"value":"A/B/C"},{"value":"A/F"},{"value":"A/"}]}]`  But actual output what i need is `[{"option":"A/","directories":[{"value":"A"},{"value":"A/B/C"},{"value":"A/F"},{"value":"A/B"}]},{"option":"A/B","directories":[{"value":"A/B"},{"value":"A/B/C"},{"value":"A/F"},{"value":"A/"}]}]`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you iterating twice? You can use just one `forEach` loop and an arrow function with destructuring:

```
angular.forEach($scope.Object2, { directories } => directories = $scope.Object1);
```